# Data binding dependency property to data object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a DependencyObject with a DependencyProperty:

```
public class DependencyObjectClass: DependencyObject
{
    public static DependencyProperty BooleanValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BooleanValue", typeof (bool), typeof (DependencyObjectClass));
    public bool BooleanValue
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(BooleanValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BooleanValueProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I also have my data source class:

```
public class DataSource: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _istrue;
    public bool IsTrue
    {
        get { return _istrue; }
        set 
        { 
            _istrue = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsTrue"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

I am trying to bind the two above objects with this code:

```
var dependencyObject = new DependencyObjectClass();
var dataSource = new DataSource();
var binding = new Binding("IsTrue");
binding.Source = dataSource;
binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(dependencyObject, DependencyObjectClass.BooleanValueProperty, binding);
```

Whenever I change the BooleanValue property on DependencyObjectClass, the DataSource does react, but it doesn't work the other way around (changing IsTrue property on DataSource does nothing for DependencyObjectClass).

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to manually handle the OnPropertyChanged event? If yes then that would be a bit disappointing, as I was expecting this to be done automatically.

Comment: Just an aside question, what is the intention of this? are you creating a custom control?

Comment: I also have seen some problem with binding bool properties .If we Notify same value from VM to View it doesnt reflect in setter of DependencyProperty.Like if you have true value of IsTrue and then you again assign true to it the setter of DependencyProperty doesnt reflect it.It means if you set the same value again it is not reflected to the setter of DependencyProperty.

Comment: HighCore, I'm basically implementing MVVM pattern on non-WPF objects. I'm coding an add-in where I need to use some third party UI elements, so I've chosen to wrap them in my own classes, derived from DependencyObject. Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> changing IsTrue property on DataSource does nothing for
>   DependencyObjectClass

I guess you conclude this from the fact that the `DependencyObjectClass.BooleanValue` property setter is never called. In fact WPF does not do that. Instead it directly sets the value of the dependency property, just like calling `SetValue` directly.

See [Checklist for Defining a Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx#checklist) and [Implications for Custom Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx#implications) for an explanation.

In order to get notified about a changed dependency property value, you would have to register a [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx) with the dependency property metadata in [DependencyProperty.Register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597502.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't occur to me to check the value instead of just watching its accessor.